# Fully Homomorphic Encryption - state of the art

Tags: homomorphic-encryption, ntru, lwe, ring-lwe

What are the latest advances in fully homomorphic encryption? First of all, I am interested in cryptosystems based on LWE / RLWE and NTRU problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the latest *real* production grade homomorphic library is Microsoft [SEAL](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/project/microsoft-seal/), which implements the BFV and the CKKS encryption schemes.

I'm not a big MS fan. There are other options to explore:

[HELib](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HElib) implements the BGV scheme with GHS optimizations.

[NuFHE](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwj30vHpx4bnAhWmQxUIHXx9D6AQFjAAegQIARAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Fnucypher%2Fnufhe&usg=AOvVaw0Ny04ezaZBmxxNHB3_vR2q) implements a GPU reference of fully homomorphic encryption on torus

Also checkout [the open group site for homomorphic encryption.](https://homomorphicencryption.org)

Comment: I would also love to hear from one of the cryptoGods that roam this board with regard to the performance of the libs I mentioned above in a production setting...